Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Many topics regarding systemctl but still looking for an answer.
I have a docker container (created with ubunto 20.04) image.
I have installed systemd (version 245.4-ubuntu3.23)
When I tried to look the status of a service (e.g. app1.service)
I received error:
MyContainer1# systemctl  status app1.service
“System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down”
I need to use this version of Ubuntu (20.04) and also the systemctl.
If I create the resources in Azure, all works fine.
Is this related to docker?
What am I missing?
